# Sending email through asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

This is my Design page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="register.aspx.cs" Inherits="register" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table style="border:1px solid" align="center">
    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td valign="top">Address:</td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAdress" TextMode="MultiLine"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email-id:</td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRegister" 
            Text="Register" onclick="btnRegister_Click" /></td></tr>
    </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my code page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(txtEmail.Text);
        msg.From = new MailAddress("mysiteadmin@peers");
        msg.Subject="thanks for registraion";
        msg.Body="thanks for registraion";
        SmtpClient obj = new SmtpClient();
        obj.Host = "sri";obj.Send(msg);
        Response.Write("<h2>Registered</h2>");

    }
```

}

```
Here am getting an error below.... can you please help
```

> Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server
>   response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server 100.64.243.189
>   (100.64.243.189:25), connect error 10061 Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.   Exception Details:
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Service not available, closing
>   transmission channel. The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP
>   server 100.64.243.189 (100.64.243.189:25), connect error 10061

```
Source Error: 
Line 21:         msg.Body="thanks for registraion";
Line 22:         SmtpClient obj = new SmtpClient();
Line 23:         obj.Host = "sri";obj.Send(msg);
Line 24:         Response.Write("<h2>Registered</h2>");
Line 25:
```

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server in your network?

Comment: Set up your SMTP server settings on web config

Comment: Sounds like that server is not up and running - can you telnet to 100.64.243.189 on port 25?

Comment: Yes i have SMTP server in my net

Comment: Is the SMTP service running? Incase if it is , is the authentication successful?

Comment: @Travis G Yes and yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be two cause:

1. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is
   inactive on the foreign host.
2. Sometimes a 10061 error is caused by either a firewall or anti-virus
   software presence on the local computer or network connection.

Either one may be blocking the ports needed to make a successful connection to the server. Either you went to the wrong host, or the server application you're trying to contact is not executing. Check the destination address you are using. Check, if you used a hostname, did it resolve to the correct address or not..

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you have a smtp server setup. add smtp server info in web.config. then try this.

you need to mention the smtp server url and the port number. [SMTp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0y6s613.aspx)

```
   SmtpClient obj = new SmtpClient(yourSmtpServerURL);
 NetworkCredential myCreds = new NetworkCredential("youremail@gmail.com", "YourPassword", "");           
            obj.Credentials = myCreds;
```

then now call `obj.send` .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set up smtp on web config file

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="smtp@server" port="25" userName="user" password="password" defaultCredentials="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply SMTP settings in web.config by putting this section inside:

```
    <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="...">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" defaultCredentials="false" userName="" password="" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

This example shows configuration for Gmail SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.Subject = "Title";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(yourEmailExpeditor);
message.Body = "content message here";

//Initialize the smtp
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(adress,int.Parse(port));
//Send the message
smtp.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give credentials.. check the below code once

```
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("Email Id");

        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("Email Id");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

        mail.Subject = "";
        mail.Body = "";


        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;

        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            "Email Id", "Password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        smtp.Send(mail);
```

You have to add below namespaces

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
```